# Picture/article which describes JSF lifecycle in detail

Tags: jsf, lifecycle

I've already seen some examples, like the one below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [javaworld.com](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2002/images/jw-1227-jsf1.jpg))</sub>

That's nice description in theory, but I'd like to see also more JSF-related picture, with FacesServlet, PhaseListeners and other stuff to understand their role and sequence of calls in all these phases of lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find here several: ["jsf lifecycle" at images.google.com](http://images.google.com/images?q=jsf%20lifecycle).

Not a picture, but a complete self-practice example with detailed explanations what exactly happens during every phase can be found here: [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html). You (at least, many do) may find it more useful than just a picture.

In the book [The Definitive Guide to JSF in Java EE 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNMHT.png), in chapter 3 "Components", page 56, the below diagram is used to summarize all aspects of the JSF lifecycle during a postback request. The numbers are in order. The book itself explains every step in detail. Copyright disclaimer: book is written by me and picture is created by me.

[image]

#### See also:

- [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check the [Life Cycle of a JavaServer Faces Page](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSFIntro10.html) tutorial from Java Sun. The tutorial has an life cycle image and some sections that explains some details of JSF.

Comment: Picture is good, but the tutorial itself is outdated. J2EE 1.4 is yet almost 10 years old. We're already at JEE 6.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of google-fu turned up [this JSF story-board](http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/storyboard_2.html). About 2/3rds down the page is a sequence diagram which breaks down the lifecycle phases, their operations, and the different components that actually perform them.

HTH.