# What exactly is java server faces?

Tags: java, asp.net, jsf

In comparison with asp.net webforms and asp.net mvc frameworks.

Comment: When you read http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/ what specific questions did you have?

Comment: What kind of framework is it? Does it focuses on mvc, mvvm, xxx? Does it have something similar to web forms page life cycle?

Comment: @Arnis L.: Please update your question with the specific issues.  Please do not add comments to a question which you own.  You can update your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I got no specific issues. And i got answer i was looking for already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JSF is a component based MVC framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-intro.htm). It runs on top of the Servlet API. You can use the JSF tags in the old fashioned JSP files or, more designed towards JSF, [in Facelets XHTML files](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets.htm).

It has a full worthy lifecycle as presented in the image below:

[image: JSF lifecycle]

*Image is extracted from [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-intro006.htm#GLPRC) of the Java EE 7 tutorial. You can find a practical playground example in [this article](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) as well.*

#### See also:

- [What is the difference between JSF, Servlet and JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)
- [Picture/article which describes JSF lifecycle in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958568/picture-article-which-describes-jsf-lifecycle-in-detail/)
- [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)

Answer (score 6):

It's like ASP.Net webforms, where you use UI Components and event-bindings to build up your web pages.