# What is meant by "the JSF runtime", and how is the "javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet" related?

Tags: jsf

I've seen references to "the JSF runtime".  I understand in some way the 'javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet" is the "entry point" to the JSF runtime. It is not clear to me what this consititues.

I gather it is something to do with lifecycle management (- an analogue for which i am faintly familiar with, from my knowledge of Serlvets + JSP - in it being a thing that does the calling of the constructor, the init() method, the Servlet's service() method and destroys the Servlet when the Container shutsdown). However, I suspect there is more to the JSF runtime than this. Should the JSF runtime simply be a thing limited to (and concerned only about) lifecycle management - I would most appreciate a little light being shed on what exactly this means for JSF (- though i understand what it means with Servlet's and JSP's), i do not see what this means specifically in terms of JSF, and would most appreciate guidance on this.

Answer (score 4):

The exact phrase "*the JSF runtime*" is indeed mentioned a several times in [the JSF  specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsf-2_3-final-eval-spec/JSF_2.3.pdf).

> Upon completion of rendering, but before state saving **the JSF runtime** must publish a
> `javax.faces.event.PostRenderViewEvent`. After doing so **the JSF runtime** must save the completed state
> using the methods of the class `StateManager`. [...]

> A JSF
> implentation must support JSR 303 Bean Validation if the environment in which **the JSF runtime** is included requires
> JSR 303 Bean Validation. [...]

> The following method gives **the JSF runtime** access to the list of listeners stored by this instance.:
> [...]

> When **the JSF runtime** is directed to shutdown by its container, the following actions must be taken. [...]

There are by the way far more hits on the exact phrase "*the runtime*" in the very same JSF specification, but I'll leave up to you to find them.

It basically boils down to **the currently configured and active JSF application**. The entire JSF ecosystem with the [`FacesServlet`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/webapp/facesservlet), [`Lifecycle`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/lifecycle/lifecycle) and [`Application`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/application/application) being ready and waiting to process a HTTP request as a Faces request. Configured either as default or overridden/customized via `faces-config.xml` JSF deployment descriptor files and/or `@FacesXxx` annotated classes.

The [`FacesServlet`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/webapp/facesservlet) is just a part of the JSF runtime. It indeed acts as the entry point of the ecosystem. If an incoming `HttpServletRequest` matches the URL pattern of the servlet mapping of the `FacesServlet`, then it will be invoked by the servletcontainer [as usual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-sessions-shared-variables-and-multithreadi). The `FacesServlet` will in turn create the [`FacesContext`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/context/facescontext) and process the request through the [`Lifecycle`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/lifecycle/lifecycle) of the [`Application`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/application/application) and finally destroy the `FacesContext` right before returning to servletcontainer.

#### See also:

- [Picture/article which describes JSF lifecycle in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958568/picture-article-which-describes-jsf-lifecycle-in-detail/)
- [Debugging JSF Life Cycle - what exactly happens in each phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914216/debugging-jsf-life-cycle-what-exactly-happens-in-each-phase/)
- [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, it looks wonderfully thorough. Much appreciated.  Apologies for my delay in responding, I unfortunately have infrequent access to the internet. I will study the above today.